# How to enable Joomla debug mode from the URL

Tags: debugging, joomla, joomla2.5, performance-testing

I often need performance information from live sites. Since I cannot show debug information to the end users, I need a way to **enable Joomla! debug mode** with a URL parameter, that is,

```
http://example.com/?debug=1
```

I have only been able to achieve this with a core hack of `includes/framework.php` at line 91 (Joomla 2.5.9):

```
define('JDEBUG', $config->debug  || JRequest::getVar('debug','0')=='1');
```

Which alternatively could be played on `configuration.php`:

```
public $debug = JRequest::getVar('debug','0')=='1';
```

I just tested overriding the configuration with a system plugin following Mark Dexter and Louis Landry's post at *[Using Plugins to Override Core Classes](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1858258&seqNum=8)*. But a quick-test with Ivan Rajkovic suggestion,

```
print_r(JLoader::getClassList());
```

shows that the configuration is already loaded, so it cannot be overridden.

Can you suggest **a better way to achieve this without a core hack?**

Is there a solution for Joomla! 3?

Comment: I think this option was removed long ago for security reasons, so no, you won't be able to do it without a core hack

Comment: No you can't do this without core hack.Also if you want to do core hack check the configuration.php public $debug = '0';

Comment: @JobinJose there's no point in setting a hack in the config file - that turns it on for everyone - and is equivalent to just turning it on on the radio buttons in the Global Config ;)

Comment: @George Wilson: the hack in the config file would be $debug = JRequest::getVar('debug','0')=='1' || '0';

Answer (score 3):

I think if you enabled the debug plugin (in the plugins list) and set its access level to Superuser or whatever your rank is, no one else will be able to see the debug information except you.

**Update**

There's [a plugin](http://archive.extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/offline/10859) (for Joomla! 1.5 though) that limit the debug output for certain IPs to make it possible for you to debug a live site without exposing it to everyone. Not sure how easy is it to make it work with Joomla! 2.5

Comment: Excellent idea, however sites are usually quite different for guests and logged in users (cache is disabled entirely for logged in users in 2.5! http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=28760) so debug is really needed without login.  Thank you for your contribution

Comment: Ohh right, that doesn't make it possible to debug for guests. Answer updated